# managedObjectContext is null if I set it as using property, but non-null if I set it as chained controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

If I use the following code in order to set AppDelegate's `managedObjectContext` to the `firstViewController`, which is just a subclass of `UITableViewController` in `AppDelegate.m`'s `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method,

```
    rootTabBarController *rootabbarcontroller = (rootTabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[rootabbarcontroller viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
    FirstViewController *firstViewController = [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];

    firstViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

and then run the simulator, the value of `managedObjectContext` is set to non-null within `FirstViewController.m`'s `viewDidLoad` method, and hence the Core Data works as expected.

However, when I tried to write the following code in the `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method:

```
_firstViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

and run the simulator, the resultant `managedObjectProperty` value within `FirstViewController.m`'s `viewDidLoad` method is set to `null`.

So I wonder why the first implementation, which is chained from the root UITabBarController to root UINavigationController to FirstViewController works within its `viewDidLoad:` method, but the latter (just directly set to its property) doesn't.

It's worth noting that I declared `@property (nonatomic, strong) FirstViewController *firstViewController;` in `AppDelegate.h` when I tried to implement in the latter way. Also set its class to the appropriate view controller in storyboard.

I've read some blogs to take the latter approach (links are not handy, sorry), so it would be possible to take the latter route to set its `managedObjectContext` value correctly and synthesize Core Data with UITableView.

So what am I missing? And is it feasible to just take the latter approach (which saves me of a lot of coding and potential unexpected bugs)? And finally, which is the better way to take?

I use Xcode 5 and iOS 7, thanks.

[updated]

If I tried to add the following line as suggested by Almas in the answer below,

```
self.firstViewController = firstViewController;
```

then I got an compile error since `firstViewController` isn't defined there.

And so I added the initialization of the `firstViewController`, by adding the following line just above the above line.

```
FirstViewController *firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
```

but then the `AppDelegate.m` looks like working correctly, but this time, an error occurred in `viewDidLoad` method of the `FirstViewController.m`, which is the same as my first reported one.

Comment: Have you tried using `NSLog` to see what the values of `rootTabBarController`, `navigationController`, and `firstViewController` are in `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`?

Comment: Yeah, I tried. None of those returned null - after all, if any of those returns null I couldn't even run the simulator correctly, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you set your local variable `firstViewController` to ivar/property before setting managed object context to it?

add:

```
self.firstViewController = firstViewController;
// or
_firstViewController = firstViewController;
```

before:

```
_firstViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

Comment: Isn't it what `@property (nonatomic, strong) FirstViewController` tries to do, right? Or is `@property` not enough and I have to write your suggested code too?

Comment: Yes, with @property you declared it. Now you need to set it.

Comment: I updated my question to reflect your answer but the things didn't change unfortunately...

Comment: @user2360798 Where are you creating UINavigationController and UITabBarController? Don't you mind posting whole `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method?

Comment: Those are within `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method. And the way to use UINavigationController and UITabBarController works as expected, just want to know why I cannot run the app without creating those two instances before set firstViewController's managedObjectContext property. And finally, my code of `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is actually just the above snippet followed by `return YES;` statement.

Comment: @user2360798 Oh, then I guess you are using storyboards. Sorry, totally forgot about them. What do you think about getting object context inside FirstViewController? You could get it through `[(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]`

Comment: Yeah, I'm using storyboard. Isn't it different from getting it from within AppDelegate.m (which is my initial code)? I wonder which way is better then.

Comment: @user2360798 I'd get from inside FirstViewController (or even create separate class for managing CoreData stack). Just getting pointer to view controller through tabbar, navbar feels a bit dirty. Also, if you even change your tabbar in storyboard in future, you'd need to update indexes in code.